# Any difference between print() and readfile() when loading an image file?

Tags: php, readfile

Just wondering if there is any difference with the two below code examples:

```
$image = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg'

$photo = file_get_contents($image);

ob_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print($photo);
ob_end_flush();
```

or...

```
$image = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg'

$photo = file_get_contents($image);

ob_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($photo);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: The second snippet doesn't work, unless `readfile($image);` was meant. Also, I would never use output buffering for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile)'s parameter is a filename, not the content itself. Therefore, you'd call it like this:

```
$image = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg'
ob_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($image);
ob_end_flush();
```

Since `readfile` reads and write chunks at a time, its memory consumption will be constant, whereas when you store the result of `file_get_contents` into `$photo`, you'll need to have enough memory to store the image.

In your case, the output buffering makes the `file_get_contents` variant demand *twice* as much memory as the image's size. For a large image, `readfile` therefore halves the memory requirements. Note that your output buffering means that the download will be delayed. If you don't need it for anything else, you will get better performance (both in actual speed and server memory requirements) if you simply disable it:

```
$image = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg'
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
if (@readfile($image) === false) {
   // print error image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's code within a current script that uses `print` to do it and since I had used `readfile` in the past to display images I forgot it took a filename. Unfortunately can't disable the output buffering as much of the script uses it. :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a very significant difference in that `readfile` takes the filename as the argument.

The second snippet should be something like

```
$image = ...
readfile($image)
```

This has the advantage of not having to store the entire file contents in memory (a string) since `readfile` emits it immediately.  Of course, if you buffer the output that is no longer true.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. Basically `print` takes the data from `file_get_contents` and outputs it, whilst `readfile` kinda does both at once without having to store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance your code would never work

```
  readfile($photo);
              ^--------------- Takes file name not string
```

PHP DOC SAYS

> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

You don't need to re event that and duplicate that with multiple other functions its just saying

```
 readfile = file_get_contents + print
```

It just like using `fopen` instead of `file_get_contents` just a get a simple content in a file

Lastly `readfile` is faster tested with 10000 loop on same image

```
Single Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.0006101131439209
    [m2] => 0.00031208992004395
)
Dual Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 3.4585757255554   
    [m2] => 2.9963381290436   <---- Faster 
)
```

`m1` & `m2` functions

```
function m1($array) {
    $photo = file_get_contents('a.png');
    ob_start();
    print($photo);
    ob_end_clean();
}

// Array clean copy
function m2($array) {
    ob_start();
    readfile('a.png');
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: Yep, accidentally glanced over that fact. Thanks!